# Updating Android SDK to latest and ADT 19

Tags: java, android, adt, dalvik, heap-memory

I am using eclipse Indigo and latest sdk and ADT 19 for my android development.

I am getting the following error after fixing the following issue:
http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

```
Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  
(com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.functions.SecuritySupport12$8) that doesn't come with an  
 associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  

Unable to execute dex: Java heap space  
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

Comment: Did you actually read the message? The solution seems pretty clear: `The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.`

Comment: how to do that? sorry. i am a noobe in it.. i did not get what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

From warning message looks like, compiler not set properly after you upgraded to ADT-19 with indigo, try and check with java compiler setting.